# Splitting based on condtions

Tags: python, dataframe

Say I have df as follows:

```py
MyCol
Red Motor
Green Taxi 
Light blue small Taxi  
Light blue big Taxi
```

I would like to split the color and the vehicle into two columns. I used this command to split the last word. But sometimes, there is a 'big' or 'small' associated with the car name. How can do the splitting with conditions?

```
df[['color','vehicle']] = df.myCol.str.rsplit(pat=' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use `extract` with a `regex` pattern

```
df['MyCol'].str.extract('^(.*?)\s((?:small|big)?\s?\w+)$')
```

---

```
            0           1
0         Red       Motor
1       Green        Taxi
2  Light blue  small Taxi
3  Light blue    big Taxi
```

Regex details:

- `^`: Matches start of the string
- `(.*?)`: first capturing group

  - `.*?`: matches any character zero or more times but as few times as possible (lazy match)
- `\s`: Matches the space
- `((?:small|big)?\s?\w+)`: Second capturing group

  - `(?:small|big)?` : matches small or big zero or one time
  - `\s?`: matches space zero or one time
  - `\w+`: matches word characters oner or more times
- `$`: matches end of the string

The `Series.str.extract` is used here to extracts two groups using a regular expression. The first group is before a whitespace and the second group is after the whitespace. The second group may contain the word "small" or "big" and returns a new DataFrame with two columns containing the extracted groups.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
data = {'MyCol': ['Red Motor', 'Green Taxi', 'Light blue small Taxi', 'Light blue big Taxi']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create new columns for color and vehicle
df['color'] = ''
df['vehicle'] = ''

# iterate through rows of the dataframe
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    words = row['MyCol'].split()
    if words[-1] == 'big' or words[-1] == 'small':
        # if last word is 'big' or 'small'
        df.at[i, 'color'] = ' '.join(words[:-2])
        df.at[i, 'vehicle'] = words[-2] + ' ' + words[-1]
    else:
        # if last word is not 'big' or 'small'
        df.at[i, 'color'] = ' '.join(words[:-1])
        df.at[i, 'vehicle'] = words[-1]

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

`str.split()` method to split the string into words, then it checks if the last word is "big" or "small" and assigns the color and vehicle accordingly.

I could have done it with regular expression but it has some annoying test cases.

Comment: Doesn't work because 1. You check `words[-1]`, which is `"Taxi"` or `"Motor"`, never `"big"` or `"small"`. 2. Even if you fix that to `[-2]`, what about inputs where the car is a two-word value, such as e.g. `"Diesel Bus"`: in these cases `words[-2]` is not `small`/`big`.

Comment: I just realized my mistake , the answer above does the trick I think.